# Shortcuts in Objective-C to concatenate NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-concatenation

Are there any shortcuts to (`stringByAppendingString:`) string concatenation in Objective-C, or shortcuts for working with `NSString` in general?

For example, I'd like to make:

```
NSString *myString = @"This";
NSString *test = [myString stringByAppendingString:@" is just a test"];
```

something more like:

```
string myString = "This";
string test = myString + " is just a test";
```

Comment: Shortest *hack* in obj-c syntax would be `[@"This" : @" works" : @" OK"];` when you extend the NSString with your own category. See answer below.

Comment: @ranReloaded ever heard of ARC?

Comment: @cheeesus Yes. Still. ARC is not GC, and retain cycles are possible. You need to be aware, if not of retain counts, at least of object ownership (graph).

Comment: I'd just like to propose '@+' as a concatenation operator. I'll expect this in the next update to Objective-C, kthxbai

Comment: Forget the @ symbol, just make Obj-C support operator overloading like C++ does! That's what I want.

Comment: @Jordão Wow that's cool... using C++ on top of Objective-C for operator overloading. Now *that* warrants some looking into.

Comment: @NicolasMiari This is not the only feature that Objective-C lacks. There are dozens of others. Quoting from the [link](http://luminaryapps.com/blog/sweetened-cocoa-the-string-class/) Jordão posted: "Objective-C is, to be blunt, a primitive language. Compare it to any modern language and you quickly find it lacking." I agree. Objective-C (early 1980s) is C (early 1970s) with the addition of a very simple and not very type-safe kind of OOP. It's ok, but compared with Java or C#, it feels very old-fashioned.

Comment: ...it all boils down to what you want to do. C# and Java might be full of "modern features", but I personally would never code computer graphics in an interpreted language when there's C or Obj-C available.

Comment: @NicolasMiari: Interpreted language? C# and Java are compiled languages. Compiled to bytecode, which is then compiled again to machine code.

Comment: You mean "[...]Which is then compiled again to machine code, at runtime, just in time".

Comment: You expectation of a + operator for strings in Objective-C belies a fundamental misunderstanding of Objective-C's design & legacy.

Comment: Things are changed now : Swift (apple new language) is more straightforward

Comment: @NicolasMiari How is allowing us to "add" strings dirty? It would do the same thing but with less typing. You don't have to worry about it bringing us down to slow junk like Java.

Comment: Because it may seem more straightforward and intuitive, but in exchange it sacrifices the kind of fine-grained control you have with e.g. `printf()`'s format specifiers (%f, %.2f, %06d etc.) Instead, you have to use `someIntegerVar.ToString()`.

Comment: Regarding modern features and feeling "dated": Objective-C introduced Automatic Reference Counting a few years ago, which is the best thing since sliced bread; literally "The Best Of Both Worlds". Meanwhile, everyone else still is stuck with garbage collectors. People developing games with e.g. Unity3d have to jump through hoops and recycle objects in  "pools" to avoid the performance hit when the undeterministic GC kicks in.

Comment: Regarding "type safety", I think it's a problem of style. For someone coming from C#/C++, having heterogeneous arrays of objects of any type might seem odd, but for someone accustomed to Objective-C/Cocoa, it's a form of dynamism and freedom; it is an advantage provided you know what you are doing. Like pretty much everything about C that younger programmers bash these days...

Comment: @Braiam: This question most definitely has to do with those tags you removed; its _subject_ is `NSString`! And the Cocoa and Cocoa Touch frameworks are the source of the `NSString` class.

Comment: If you're doing low-level work, use C, assembly, or (if you have a background in hardware) Verilog (not VHDL, because VHDL is terrible). If you're doing high level work, use python or haskell. If you're doing low-level work, but want the power of a higher level language, use C++. Don't like garbage collection? C++ has smart pointers. The only reason anyone would ever write anything in Objective C is to target Apple products, and frankly that's not a good reason. Objective C combines the worst of both worlds; the error-proneness of C with the unfathomable prolixity of Java.

Comment: Just in case anyone is curious, in Swift you *are* able to use `let name = "Long" + "face"`

Answer (score 631, accepted):

Two answers I can think of... neither is particularly as pleasant as just having a concatenation operator.

First, use an `NSMutableString`, which has an `appendString` method, removing some of the need for extra temp strings.

Second, use an `NSArray` to concatenate via the `componentsJoinedByString` method.

Comment: Although the other option has many upvotes, I think this is the best answer if you don't know all your strings upon construction. Every time you append a string, you're creating a lot of overhead. Using a mutable string removes that problem.

Comment: +1 Agree w @Eli. These are generally the best solutions. NSArray -componentsJoinedByString can be done in a single line pretty well: string = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"This", "Is", "A", "Test", nil] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

Comment: +1 for this answer. `[NSMutableString appendString]` is more memory friendly than `[NSString stringByAppendingStrings]`.

Comment: @RobNapier:Now with the new array literal syntax, it is even better.

Comment: The `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", three, two, one];` technique seems the most elegant.  It should be the selected answer.

Comment: Just to be clear. editable array = `NSMutableArray`, editable dictionary = `NSMutableDictionary`, editable string = `NSMutableString`. When using a NSString you will not be able to change a portion of the value.

Comment: @ekillaby Note, however, that in that case, `three` would come first.

Answer (score 1182):

### An option:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", one, two, three];
```

### Another option:

I'm guessing you're not happy with multiple appends (a+b+c+d), in which case you could do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [Util append:one, @" ", two, nil]); // "one two"
NSLog(@"%@", [Util append:three, @"/", two, @"/", one, nil]); // three/two/one
```

using something like

```
+ (NSString *) append:(id) first, ...
{
    NSString * result = @"";
    id eachArg;
    va_list alist;
    if(first)
    {
        result = [result stringByAppendingString:first];
        va_start(alist, first);
        while (eachArg = va_arg(alist, id)) 
        result = [result stringByAppendingString:eachArg];
        va_end(alist);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @pablasso Agreed. The Util method is pretty ugly. If you wanted such a thing, it should be done as a NSString category with a name like +stringByAppendingStrings:. Even a straight-up function with a name like NSStringForAppendedStrings(...) would be better than a static method in a class like Util (anything with "Util" in the name is likely poorly factored). The function is also better implemented with an NSMutableString and -appendString to avoid creating an unbounded set of temporary autoreleased NSStrings.

Comment: With large strings this can waste memory.  Recommended is something more like StringBuilder in real programming languages.  Then you could just figure out how much memory is needed before you actually start appending.  The above approach could be refactored to do this.  However, it would be better to make a StringBuilder object as this would save the user of it from having to keep track of a list of all the strings they need combined.

Comment: how do you import Util? this IDE is frustrating (no suggested "import something.Util" like on eclipse, and I find no mention of "Util" anywhere.

Is this a class I'm supposed to code myself?

Comment: stringWithFormat is not only very elegant, it is also much more powerful. You use it with @"%@%@" to concatenate two strings, @"%@%@%@" to concatenate three strings, but you can put any extra characters inside, print numbers, reorder parameters if you like and so on. The format string can be localised, making it ten times more powerful. String concatenation is for beginners.

Answer (score 156):

If you have 2 NSString **literals**, you can also just do this:

```
NSString *joinedFromLiterals = @"ONE " @"MILLION " @"YEARS " @"DUNGEON!!!";
```

That's also useful for joining #defines:

```
#define STRINGA @"Also, I don't know "
#define STRINGB @"where food comes from."
#define JOINED STRINGA STRINGB
```

Enjoy.

Comment: @CristiBăluță :) But this works only with _literals_ not with dynamically created NSString instances.

Comment: You actually don't need the `@`s on the strings after the first. `@"I" " really" " enjoy"...`

Comment: You should probably want to put STRINGA and STRINGB within parenthesis, otherwise you might get weird results when the macro is resolved. #define JOINED (STRINGA STRINGB)

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug Then why this `NSString* const SQL_CREATE_TABLE_str = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " TABLE_NAME @" (...);";` doesn't work?
I'm having `Expected '@' in program` error :(

Comment: @Vagif how is `TABLE_NAME` defined?

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug I tried both ways
`NSString* const EVENT_TABLE_NAME = @"events";`
and
`#define EVENT_TABLE_NAME @"events";`
neither worked.

Comment: Just so you know, you shouldn't have the `;` in the `#define` – `#define` doesn't care about it, so it'll be expanded at the end. This will mess up your concatenation.

Answer (score 85):

I keep returning to this post and always end up sorting through the answers to find this simple solution that works with as many variables as needed:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", three, two, one];
```

For example:

```
NSString *urlForHttpGet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/login/username/%@/userid/%i", userName, userId];
```

Comment: Thx for posting this! I'm completely new to Objective-C and I thought that stringWithFormat was a variable name, hahahah. Thx for the example!

Answer (score 57):

Create a method:

```
- (NSString *)strCat: (NSString *)one: (NSString *)two
{
    NSString *myString;
    myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", one , two];
    return myString;
}
```

Then, in whatever function you need it in, set your string or text field or whatever to the return value of this function.

Or, to make a shortcut, convert the NSString into a C++ string and use the '+' there.

Answer (score 47):

Well, as colon is kind of special symbol, but *is* part of method signature, it is possible to exted the `NSString` with category to add this **non-idiomatic** style of string concatenation:

```
[@"This " : @"feels " : @"almost like " : @"concatenation with operators"];
```

You can define as many colon separated arguments as you find useful... ;-)

For a good measure, I've also added `concat:` with variable arguments that takes `nil` terminated list of strings.

```
//  NSString+Concatenation.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (Concatenation)

- (NSString *):(NSString *)a;
- (NSString *):(NSString *)a :(NSString *)b;
- (NSString *):(NSString *)a :(NSString *)b :(NSString *)c;
- (NSString *):(NSString *)a :(NSString *)b :(NSString *)c :(NSString *)d;

- (NSString *)concat:(NSString *)strings, ...;

@end

//  NSString+Concatenation.m

#import "NSString+Concatenation.h"

@implementation NSString (Concatenation)

- (NSString *):(NSString *)a { return [self stringByAppendingString:a];}
- (NSString *):(NSString *)a :(NSString *)b { return [[self:a]:b];}
- (NSString *):(NSString *)a :(NSString *)b :(NSString *)c
    { return [[[self:a]:b]:c]; }
- (NSString *):(NSString *)a :(NSString *)b :(NSString *)c :(NSString *)d
    { return [[[[self:a]:b]:c]:d];}

- (NSString *)concat:(NSString *)strings, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, strings);

    NSString *s;    
    NSString *con = [self stringByAppendingString:strings];

    while((s = va_arg(args, NSString *))) 
        con = [con stringByAppendingString:s];

    va_end(args);
    return con;
}
@end

//  NSString+ConcatenationTest.h

#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>
#import "NSString+Concatenation.h"

@interface NSString_ConcatenationTest : SenTestCase

@end

//  NSString+ConcatenationTest.m

#import "NSString+ConcatenationTest.h"

@implementation NSString_ConcatenationTest

- (void)testSimpleConcatenation 
{
    STAssertEqualObjects([@"a":@"b"], @"ab", nil);
    STAssertEqualObjects([@"a":@"b":@"c"], @"abc", nil);
    STAssertEqualObjects([@"a":@"b":@"c":@"d"], @"abcd", nil);
    STAssertEqualObjects([@"a":@"b":@"c":@"d":@"e"], @"abcde", nil);
    STAssertEqualObjects([@"this " : @"is " : @"string " : @"concatenation"],
     @"this is string concatenation", nil);
}

- (void)testVarArgConcatenation 
{
    NSString *concatenation = [@"a" concat:@"b", nil];
    STAssertEqualObjects(concatenation, @"ab", nil);

    concatenation = [concatenation concat:@"c", @"d", concatenation, nil];
    STAssertEqualObjects(concatenation, @"abcdab", nil);
}
```

Comment: I downvoted this a year ago because it's not a very good answer. To cope with concatenating a large number of strings, Palimondo's implementation requires either implementing a large number of very similar looking methods, or calling the methods several times, resulting in a large chunk of code that essentially just concatenates strings. Using this approach, you don't get any benefit over a simple `stringWithFormat:`. Not to mention the lack of named parameters which is not only non-standard but also confusing.

Comment: The original asker mentioned `stringByAppendingString`, and he never said anything about using more than two arguments. I like this answer better than the accepted one. It's pretty clever.

Answer (score 40):

Use `stringByAppendingString:` this way:

```
NSString *string1, *string2, *result;

string1 = @"This is ";
string2 = @"my string.";

result = [result stringByAppendingString:string1];
result = [result stringByAppendingString:string2];
```

OR

```
result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"This is "];
result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"my string."];
```

Comment: You do realize that you're suggesting the exact thing he wanted *not* to do, right?

Answer (score 32):

**Macro:**

```
// stringConcat(...)
//     A shortcut for concatenating strings (or objects' string representations).
//     Input: Any number of non-nil NSObjects.
//     Output: All arguments concatenated together into a single NSString.

#define stringConcat(...) \
    [@[__VA_ARGS__] componentsJoinedByString:@""]
```

**Test Cases:**

```
- (void)testStringConcat {
    NSString *actual;

    actual = stringConcat(); //might not make sense, but it's still a valid expression.
    STAssertEqualObjects(@"", actual, @"stringConcat");

    actual = stringConcat(@"A");
    STAssertEqualObjects(@"A", actual, @"stringConcat");

    actual = stringConcat(@"A", @"B");
    STAssertEqualObjects(@"AB", actual, @"stringConcat");

    actual = stringConcat(@"A", @"B", @"C");
    STAssertEqualObjects(@"ABC", actual, @"stringConcat");

    // works on all NSObjects (not just strings):
    actual = stringConcat(@1, @" ", @2, @" ", @3);
    STAssertEqualObjects(@"1 2 3", actual, @"stringConcat");
}
```

---

**Alternate macro:** (if you wanted to enforce a minimum number of arguments)

```
// stringConcat(...)
//     A shortcut for concatenating strings (or objects' string representations).
//     Input: Two or more non-nil NSObjects.
//     Output: All arguments concatenated together into a single NSString.

#define stringConcat(str1, str2, ...) \
    [@[ str1, str2, ##__VA_ARGS__] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: Haven't checked this question in a while, but I'm leaning towards accepting this as the right answer after all these years!

Comment: This also arguably has better behaviour than `-[NSString stringByAppendingString:]` for this use case — with the former you'll get an exception if the argument is `nil` but not if the receiver is. So it's conceivably 50% odds on a mistake in your string feeder failing silently and 50% on an exception. With `stringConcat` you're guaranteed an exception on any `nil`, anywhere in the list. Which at least is more predictable.

Answer (score 27):

Shortcut by creating AppendString (AS) macro ...

```
#define AS(A,B)    [(A) stringByAppendingString:(B)]

NSString *myString = @"This";

NSString *test = AS(myString,@" is just a test");
```

**Note:**

If using a macro, of course just do it with variadic arguments, see EthanB's answer.

Comment: Cool! I still think the Util above is a much more elegant solution; you can append only one string with this macro, right?

Comment: True, the AS macro above does one append per line of code.  If multiple appends are a common need, then more macros can be created.  For example, a macro to append two strings:

<pre>
#define A2S(A,B,C)    [[(A) stringByAppendingString:(B)] stringByAppendingString:(C)]
</pre>

Comment: Or, simply shorten the typing required with a macro like "#define AS stringByAppendingString", then just use "AS" where your would normally type "stringByAppendingString", and enjoy multiple appends per line of code.

Comment: The problem with these macros is that they undermine one of the major goals of Objective-C, which is readability. It's extremely unclear what "AS" does. Saving a few keystrokes (most of which are handled with autocompletion) at the expense of readability is seldom a good trade-off. There are exceptions (the @"" syntax is much more readable than having to use +stringWithUTF8String: every time), but the goal should still be readability rather than simply brevity. You write once, but you debug forever.

Comment: Hi Rob - I can't agree with you in this.  Sure, "AS" is a bad name.  It should be named perhaps "CAT".

Answer (score 27):

When building requests for web services, I find doing something like the following is very easy and makes concatenation readable in Xcode:

```
NSString* postBody = {
    @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
    @" <soap:Body>"
    @"  <WebServiceMethod xmlns=\"\">"
    @"   <parameter>test</parameter>"
    @"  </WebServiceMethod>"
    @" </soap:Body>"
    @"</soap:Envelope>"
};
```

Comment: For an objective-c noob can you explain what this syntax is doing?  Is this creating an array of strings and joining them somewhow?  A reference to any docs would be cool too.

Comment: @NormanH: This is actually part of the C language. After a little digging, I was able to find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxss3ska(v=vs.80).aspx). It states under the "String concatenation" phase: All adjacent string and wide-string literals are concatenated. For example, "String " "concatenation" becomes "String concatenation".

Answer (score 13):

```
NSString *label1 = @"Process Name: ";
NSString *label2 = @"Process Id: ";
NSString *processName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];
NSString *processID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processIdentifier]];
NSString *testConcat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", label1, processName, label2, processID];
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's a simple way, using the new array literal syntax:

```
NSString * s = [@[@"one ", @"two ", @"three"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
                  ^^^^^^^ create array ^^^^^
                                               ^^^^^^^ concatenate ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 9):

```
NSString *myString = @"This";
NSString *test = [myString stringByAppendingString:@" is just a test"];
```

After a couple of years now with Objective C I think this is the best way to work with Objective C to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Start keying in "N" in your Xcode application and it autocompletes to "NSString".
key in "str" and it autocompletes to "stringByAppendingString". So the keystrokes are quite limited.

Once you get the hang of hitting the "@" key and tabbing the process of writing readable code no longer becomes a problem. It is just a matter of adapting.

Comment: You do realize that you're suggesting the exact thing he wanted ***not*** to do, right?

Answer (score 8):

The only way to make `c = [a stringByAppendingString: b]` any shorter is to use autocomplete at around the `st` point. The `+` operator is part of C, which doesn't know about Objective-C objects.

Comment: You do realize that you're suggesting the exact thing he wanted **not** to do, right? At the very least, a `#define` could be used to shorten it.

Answer (score 8):

How about shortening `stringByAppendingString` and use a **#define**:

```
#define and stringByAppendingString
```

Thus you would use:

```
NSString* myString = [@"Hello " and @"world"];
```

Problem is that it only works for two strings, you're required to wrap additional brackets for more appends:

```
NSString* myString = [[@"Hello" and: @" world"] and: @" again"];
```

Comment: XCode7 won't let you use this option anymore -- says "and" is a reserved word. However, you can use "cat" instead, for conCATenation. I did and your solution works perfectly and is extremely simple.

Answer (score 8):

```
NSString *result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", @"Hello", @"World"];
```

Answer (score 7):

```
NSString *label1 = @"Process Name: ";
NSString *label2 = @"Process Id: ";
NSString *processName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];
NSString *processID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processIdentifier]];
NSString *testConcat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", label1, processName, label2, processID];
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried this code. it's worked for me.

```
NSMutableString * myString=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
myString=[myString stringByAppendingString:@"first value"];
myString=[myString stringByAppendingString:@"second string"];
```

Comment: This is the worst abuse of an NSMutableString ever. The whole point of NSMutableString is that you don't need methods creating autoreleased strings but can modify the string itself.

Comment: Agree. At least use [`appendString:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablestring/1417883-appendstring?language=objc) if you're using a `NSMutableString`.

Answer (score 6):

Was trying the following in the `lldb` pane

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", three, two, one];
```

which errors.

instead use alloc and `initWithFormat` method:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", @"three", @"two", @"one"];
```

Comment: ...wish I had enough reputation to comment but hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 4):

This is for better logging, and logging only - based on dicius excellent multiple argument method. I define a Logger class, and call it like so:

```
[Logger log: @"foobar ", @" asdads ", theString, nil];
```

Almost good, except having to end the var args with "nil" but I suppose there's no way around that in Objective-C.

Logger.h

```
@interface Logger : NSObject {
}
+ (void) log: (id) first, ...;
@end
```

Logger.m

```
@implementation Logger

+ (void) log: (id) first, ...
{
    // TODO: make efficient; handle arguments other than strings
    // thanks to @diciu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c
    NSString * result = @"";
    id eachArg;
    va_list alist;
    if(first)
    {
        result = [result stringByAppendingString:first];
        va_start(alist, first);
        while (eachArg = va_arg(alist, id)) 
        {
            result = [result stringByAppendingString:eachArg];
        }
        va_end(alist);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}

@end
```

In order to only **concat** strings, I'd define a Category on NSString and add a static (+) concatenate method to it that looks exactly like the log method above except it returns the string. It's on NSString because it's a string method, and it's static because you want to create a new string from 1-N strings, not call it on any one of the strings that are part of the append.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSNumber *lat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:destinationMapView.camera.target.latitude];
NSNumber *lon = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:destinationMapView.camera.target.longitude];
NSString *DesconCatenated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@",lat,lon];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try stringWithFormat:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %d", "The", "Answer", "Is", 42];
```

Comment: Why does this have 2 downvotes?  Is it because this was already mentioned in another answer?

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with strings often I find it easier to make the source file ObjC++, then I can concatenate std::strings using the second method shown in the question.

```
std::string stdstr = [nsstr UTF8String];

//easier to read and more portable string manipulation goes here...

NSString* nsstr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:stdstr.c_str()];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use NSArray as

```
NSString *string1=@"This"

NSString *string2=@"is just"

NSString *string3=@"a test"  

NSArray *myStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:string1, string2, string3,nil];

NSString *fullLengthString = [myStrings componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

or

you can use

```
NSString *imageFullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@.", string1,string2,string3];
```

Answer (score 3):

My preferred method is this:

```
NSString *firstString = @"foo";
NSString *secondString = @"bar";
NSString *thirdString = @"baz";

NSString *joinedString = [@[firstString, secondString, thirdString] join];
```

You can achieve it by adding the join method to NSArray with a category:

```
#import "NSArray+Join.h"
@implementation NSArray (Join)
-(NSString *)join
{
    return [self componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
@end
```

`@[]` it's the short definition for `NSArray`, I think this is the fastest method to concatenate strings.

If you don't want to use the category, use directly the `componentsJoinedByString:` method:

```
NSString *joinedString = [@[firstString, secondString, thirdString] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

Either of these formats work in XCode7 when I tested:

```
NSString *sTest1 = {@"This" " and that" " and one more"};
NSString *sTest2 = {
  @"This"
  " and that"
  " and one more"
};

NSLog(@"\n%@\n\n%@",sTest1,sTest2);
```

For some reason, you only need the @ operator character on the first string of the mix.

However, it doesn't work with variable insertion. For that, you can use [this extremely simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11320175/105539) with the exception of using a macro on "cat" instead of "and".

Comment: how to to make this? e.g: sTest3 = sTest1 + sTest2;

Comment: @user285594 That was the point of the question: that syntax is not allowed in Objective-C. See the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

For all Objective C lovers that need this in a UI-Test:

```
-(void) clearTextField:(XCUIElement*) textField{

    NSString* currentInput = (NSString*) textField.value;
    NSMutableString* deleteString = [NSMutableString new];

    for(int i = 0; i < currentInput.length; ++i) {
        [deleteString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 8]];
    }
    [textField typeText:deleteString];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listOfCatalogIDs =[@[@"id[]=",listOfCatalogIDs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that u don't know how many strings there.

```
NSMutableArray *arrForStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[allMyStrings count]; i++) {
    NSString *str = [allMyStrings objectAtIndex:i];
    [arrForStrings addObject:str];
}
NSString *readyString = [[arrForStrings mutableCopy] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by `NSMutableString` idea from Chris, I make a perfect macro imho.
It supports insert nil elements without any Exceptions.

```
#import <libextobjc/metamacros.h>

#define STR_CONCAT(...) \
    ({ \
        __auto_type str__ = [NSMutableString string]; \
        metamacro_foreach_cxt(never_use_immediately_str_concatify_,, str__, __VA_ARGS__) \
        (NSString *)str__.copy; \
    })

#define never_use_immediately_str_concatify_(INDEX, CONTEXT, VAR) \
    [CONTEXT appendString:VAR ?: @""];
```

Example:

```
STR_CONCAT(@"button_bg_", @(count).stringValue, @".png"); 
// button_bg_2.png
```

If you like, you can use `id` type as parameter by using `[VAR description]` instead of `NSString`.