# SOAP action in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using thid code in  android,I need the same code in iPhone..with appropriate syntex

```
NSString *soap = soapStart + "<" + soapAction + " xmlns:m='http://www.aras-corp.com/'>" + body + "</"+ soapAction + ">" + soapEnd;
```

error appers on screen "invalid operands in binary +(have struct 'Struct NSString*' ans 
'char *'
I am first time trying to use soap in my application
alternate code woukd b appreciated

Thankx in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Concatenate String in Objective-C (iPhone) ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158860/how-to-concatenate-string-in-objective-c-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't concatenate a larger `NSString` from smaller strings using the "+" operator, like you do in [Java](http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/04/06/java-string-concatenation/).

Instead, you create a new `NSString` from other `NSString` strings, using a method called [`+stringWithFormat:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithFormat_):

```
NSString *soap = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ <%@ xmlns:m='http://www.aras-corp.com/'>%@%@", soapStart, soapAction, body, soapEnd];
```

Comment: @talktobijju : don't forget the @ for String declaration in Objective-C