# Appending string to UILabel text?

Tags: iphone, string

I'm starting to develop for the iPhone. I have a beginner-type question, I'm sure:

I have this, which works:

```
testLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ to %@", testLabel.text, newLabelText];
```

I wish I could use the "+=" operator, but I get a compile error (Invalid operands to binary +, have 'struct NSString *' and 'struct NSString *'):

```
testLabel.text += [NSString stringWithFormat:@"to %@", newLabelText];
```

Why can't I do this?

Also, how can I shorten my first snippet of code?

Comment: Try to use the solution posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the `+=` operator because C and Objective-C do not allow operator overloading.  You're trying to use `+=` with two pointer types, which is not allowed -- if the left-hand side of a `+=` expression has a pointer type, then the right-hand side must be of an integral type, and the result is pointer arithmetic, which is not what you want in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Think about using an NSMutableString - you can use the `appendString:` method, as in:

```
NSMutableString *str = [@"hello" mutableCopy];
[str appendString:@" world!"];
```

Answer (score 2):

That can't be done because ObjectiveC does not support it, ObjectiveC is a small layer over C.

```
testLabel.text = [testLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@" to %@", newLabelText];
```

Answer (score 1):

NSString are NOT mutable (they can't be changed), that's why you can't use +=.

NSMutableString can be changed. You might be able to use them here.

Your code is already pretty minimal. Objective-C is a expressive language so just get used to long, descriptive function and variable names.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
// usage: label.text += "abc"
public func += (a:inout String?, b:String) {
    a = (a ?? "") + b
}
```

give this custom operator a try:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "abc"
label.text += "_def"
print(label.text)    // “abc_def”
```