# How to concatenate two numbers in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How can I concatenate two numbers like 7 and 6 to result in the number 76, or 3 and 3 so the result is 33, in objective-c?

Comment: That's not adding, that's concatenation.

Comment: Edit to reflect the original intention.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no built in symbol to concatenate numbers. However, you can accomplish this by doing:

```
int first; /* Assuming this is initialized to the first number */
int second; /* Assuming this is initalized to the second number */
int myVal = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",first, second] intValue];
```

Comment: Parsing format strings is expensive.  Use -stringByAppendingString: when you can.

Comment: That would require two separate memory allocations, which could be more expensive than parsing this (simple) format expression string. At any rate, I don't think the performance of either method will be a huge issue.

Comment: Agreed here with Mike. The complexity of setting up two strings from integers and concatenating them is unlikely to be better than the +stringWithFormat for this problem. It would certainly require profiling to know for certain, since the other common way, using NSNumber -stringValue, could be even more expensive. Even if you already had the strings, I'd be very curious of the actual cost of +stringWithFormat versus -stringByAppendingString, especially in the case of more than 2 elements, and only profiling would tell us. Cocoa makes no promises about efficiency in either case.

Answer (score 5):

FirstNum * 10 + secondNum :-)

Answer (score 2):

That's not a numeric operation, it's string concatenation.

[Shortcuts in Objective-C to concatenate NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

If you want two numbers x and y to add to xy, you can do

10*x + y.

For 7 and 6

7*10 + 6 = 76

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about objective-c but I would say:

- If you get the numbers from an array, like nums= array(7,6), initialize result= 0 and then do a foreach on them. For each value you find, do : res= res*10 + value. At the end, even if you got 7 numbers to concatenate you'll get the result right. ie:

  Array nums= Array(7,6,8,9);
  int res= 0;
  int value;
  foreach (value in nums)
    res= res*10 + value;
- If you can use strings, just concatenate them like suggested above. there is probably a function to concatenate all values from an array as well to make it flexible.

Hope it helps

C^