# How to concatenate a CHAR

Tags: objective-c

really basic question, I have a string to generate as SQL statement that I need to run through a loop to add all the relevant criteria. How do I concatenate the statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate strings in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c)

Comment: Do you need to do this using NSString or would a straight sprintf work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this post:

[Shortcuts in Objective-C to concatenate NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c)

Comment: Lots of dodgy answers in that one, although the accepted answer is ok.  Summary is to pick between stringWithFormat: and stringByAppendingString:

Comment: If you want to point out duplicates, use comments not answers - especially if you are adding no content on your own.