# How to do an equivalent on php or perl's & in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I concatenate strings in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c)

I have this:

```
[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://myurlc.co.uk/?no="]]
```

I basically want to do this:

```
[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://myurlc.co.uk/?no=" & tmpString]]
```

How would I do that in Objective-C?

Comment: What is the `&` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[@"http://myurlc.co.uk/?no=" stringByAppendingString: tmpString]
```

- [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)
- [Creating and Converting String Objects](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html)

Answer (score -3):

Look at [Shortcuts in Objective-C to concatenate NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c)

Comment: Use comments to point out duplicates, especially if you don't add any content of your own.