# ipad sending api for sms through email

Tags: api, ipad, sms

I need my app to send a mail that becomes an SMS,

in order for the API from the ISP (Internet Service Provider), I need to generate the following ftp>

https://smsgw.exetel.com.au/sendsms/api_sms.php?
username=xxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxx&mobilenumber=xxxxxxxx&message=x
xxxxxxx&sender=xxxxxxxxx&messagetype=Text&referencenumber=xxxxxx

so, whats the best way to generate this ftp (with out going to the browser, or automatically doing it)

to send the email that becomes sms?

the have another command to get the bulk sms>
Bulk SMS Sending Example Request:

//smsgw.exetel.com.au/sendsms/api_sms.php?
username=xxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxx&mobilenumber=xxxxxxxx&message=x
xxxxxxx&sender=xxxxxxxxx&messagetype=Text&referencenumber=xxxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate the URL, have you tried concatenating strings?

[Shortcuts in Objective-C to concatenate NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c)

For actually loading the URL, have you tried NSURL?

http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSURL