# Email CSV of a SQLite DB in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, csv

My application consists of a sqlite db with several tables. Managed via Core Data. I want to generate CSV of the database and mail it to a certain mail address on a button pressed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to exporting csv is located here: [How to export Core Data entity to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440396/how-to-export-core-data-entity-to-a-csv-file)

The answer to sending this file then with Mail is located here: [pdf as an email attachment in iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846338/pdf-as-an-email-attachment-in-ios-device)

Very straight forward! You don't have to save the file to disc, as you can handle it directly to the mailComposer!

Enjoy!