# iPhone:Problem with String Concatenation

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I concatenate strings in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c)

Hello,

I am retrieving 10 separate strings from an XML parser. I want to append all the strings together. I checked for string concatenation in Obj-C and tried the below code, but it doesn't work as expected. Every time it overwrites with the new string.

```
 NSString *newstring; // Global variable

[newstring stringByAppendingString:newStrGotFromXML];
```

Could someone guide me to resolve this?

Thank you!

Comment: are you calling `NSString *newstring;` every time you want to append the string (I hope you're not cause I believe that may be the problem)?

Answer (score 1):

the stringByAppendingString returns a new string by putting the two together, it doesn't modify either of the original strings. You probably want to use an NSMutableString. With that you can use the appendString method.