# Objective-C difference in concatentation methods

Tags: objective-c, append, stringwithformat

Clarification question here. 
I was originally attempting to concatenate two strings using the `stringByAppendingString` method:

```
NSString *dataString = @",";
NSInteger i = 0;
NSString *cycleCountString = @"";
for (i = 0; i<[[self cycleList] count]; i++) {

    cycleCountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cycle#%d,",i];
    [dataString stringByAppendingString:cycleCountString];
}
NSLog(@"DataString is: %@",dataString);
```

However, the NSLog was just outputing "`,`" as if `cycleCountString` was not being appended to `dataString`.

After reading:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c , I was able to fix the issue by instead doing a `stringWithFromat`:

```
NSString *dataString = @",";
NSInteger i = 0;
NSString *cycleCountString = @"";
for (i = 0; i<[[self cycleList] count]; i++) {

    cycleCountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cycle#%d,",i];
    dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",dataString,cycleCountString];


}
NSLog(@"DataString is: %@",dataString);
```

any idea why the previous method wasn't working? Does `stringByAppendingString` not work the way I think it does?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never updating the value of dataString.

```
dataString = [dataString stringByAppendingString: cycleCountString];
```

Comment: No problem :) I miss stuff like that all the time.

Answer (score 1):

`NSString` instances are immutable - you can't change them.  `stringByAppendingString:` doesn't change your original `NSString` instance, it creates a new `NSString` and returns that.

The new version works because you assign the result of `stringWithFormat:` to `dataString`.  You could make the old version work with something like this:

```
dataString = [dataString stringByAppendingString:cycleCountString];
```

Answer (score 1):

Example in documentation

```
NSString *errorTag = @"Error: ";
NSString *errorString = @"premature end of file.";
NSString *errorMessage = [errorTag stringByAppendingString:errorString];
```

produces the string “Error: premature end of file.”.

Answer (score -1):

because u didn't assign agian to datastring

```
NSString *dataString = @",";
NSInteger i = 0;
NSString *cycleCountString = @"";
for (i = 0; i<[[self cycleList] count]; i++) {

    cycleCountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cycle#%d,",i];

    dataString=[dataString stringByAppendingString:cycleCountString];//this Line
}

NSLog(@"DataString is: %@",dataString);
```

DataString is: ,cycle#0,cycle#1,cycle#2,