# Method returns NSString as nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsthread

I have method which builds NSString and returns it correctly.
However if i call the same method from separate thread it returns nil even though my NSString is not nil in line with return.

I get request = nil in "getPhones" method.

"return request" in "createSelectPhonesRequest" ontains valid string.

"getXmlRow" actually builds the string.

```
+ (void)getUserPhones:(User *)user
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [DataManager getPhones:user];

    [pool release];
}

+ (void)getPhones:(User*)user
{
    NSString *request = [XMLBuilder createSelectPhonesRequest:user.NickName];
    NSString *getAddressesResponce = [TrafficManager sendRequest:request];      
}


+(NSString*) createSelectPhonesRequest:(NSString*)nickName
{
    NSString *request;
    NSMutableArray *attributes;
    NSMutableArray *attributesValues;

    /*** root ***/
    attributes = [NSMutableArray new];
    attributesValues = [NSMutableArray new];

    //time
    [attributes addObject:xmlAt.time];
    [attributesValues addObject:[NSDate getXmlFormattedDateFromCurrentDate]];
    //action
    [attributes addObject:xmlAt.action];    
    [attributesValues addObject:xmlAV.selectPhones];


    request = [XMLBuilder getXmlRow:xmlEl.envelop 
                         attributes:attributes 
                   attributesValues:attributesValues 
                              value:nil 
                              close:YES];
    [attributes release];
    [attributesValues release];


    return request;
}


+(NSString*) getXmlRow:(NSString*)element 
               attributes:(NSMutableArray*)attributes 
         attributesValues:(NSMutableArray*)attributesValues 
                    value:(NSString*)value 
                    close:(BOOL)close

{
    //open tag
    NSString* xmlRow = @"<";    
    //tag
    xmlRow = [xmlRow stringByAppendingString:element];
    //attrivutes+values
    if (attributes && attributesValues)
        for (int i=0; i<[attributes count]; i++)
        {
            NSString *attribute = (NSString*) [attributes objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *attributeValue = (NSString*) [attributesValues objectAtIndex:i];

            xmlRow = [xmlRow stringByAppendingString:@" "];
            xmlRow = [xmlRow stringByAppendingString:(attribute)];      
            xmlRow = [xmlRow stringByAppendingString:@"=\""];
            xmlRow = [xmlRow stringByAppendingString:attributeValue];       
            xmlRow = [xmlRow stringByAppendingString:@"\""];
        }
    //end tag
    xmlRow = [xmlRow stringByAppendingString:@">"];
    //value
    if (value != nil)
        xmlRow = [xmlRow stringByAppendingString:value];
    //close tag
    if (close)
        xmlRow = [xmlRow stringByAppendingString:[self closeElement:element]];
    return xmlRow;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c use it how usefull for you

Comment: This should work fine for me either, but it is not. It does only if i run it synchronously without thread.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have not created autorelease pool for the thread. Every thread must have it's own autorelease pool.

Comment: I do have autorelease pool. Probably autoreleaseing does the problem. But i tryed to allocate the string but got the same effect.

Comment: Is your XML valid for the thread call? Your new edit has almost no similarity with your previous simple example which leaded me to think about autorelease pool.

Comment: yes it is. i did not post all the createSelectPhonesRequest because there is no need. all the lines in there are the same. Did you notice that all my methods are static?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should properly Initialize the string like,

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello"];
```

Comment: It didn't help. Still i get nil in calling method.

Comment: NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
//then ur code
return [myString autoRelease];

Comment: Got the same effect. Maybe because my method is static there is some problem.