# How to insert a character into a NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsstring

How do I insert a space to a NSString.

I need to add a space at index 5 into:

```
NString * dir = @"abcdefghijklmno";
```

To get this result:

```
abcde fghijklmno
```

with:

```
NSLOG (@"%@", dir);
```

Comment: please explain your question in brief..

Comment: I need to add in a NSString one character (space)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You need to use `NSMutableString`

```
NSMutableString *mu = [NSMutableString stringWithString:dir];
[mu insertString:@" " atIndex:5];
```

or you could use those method to split your string :

> – substringFromIndex:
>   – substringWithRange:
>   – substringToIndex:

and recombine them after with

> – stringByAppendingFormat:
>   – stringByAppendingString:
>   – stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:

But that way is more trouble that it's worth. And since `NSString` is immutable, you would bet lot of object creation for nothing.

---

```
NSString *s = @"abcdefghijklmnop";
NSMutableString *mu = [NSMutableString stringWithString:s];
[mu insertString:@"  ||  " atIndex:5];
//  This is one option
s = [mu copy];
//[(id)s insertString:@"er" atIndex:7]; This will crash your app because s is not mutable
//  This is an other option
s = [NSString stringWithString:mu];
//  The Following code is not good
s = mu;
[mu replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [mu length]) withString:@"Changed string!!!"];
NSLog(@" s == %@ : while mu == %@ ", s, mu);  
//  ----> Not good because the output is the following line
// s == Changed string!!! : while mu == Changed string!!!
```

Which can lead to difficult to debug problems.
That is the reason why `@property` for string are usually define as `copy` so if you get a `NSMutableString`, by making a copy you are sure it won't change because of some other unexpected code.

I tend to prefer `s = [NSString stringWithString:mu];` because you don't get the confusion of copying a mutable object and having back an immutable one.

Comment: This is good, but you can get it shorter by using `mutableCopy`.  `dir = [[dir mutableCopy] insertString:@" " atIndex:5];`

Comment: then you can do this?

dir = mu ?

Answer (score 4):

And here, for example, is how to insert a space every 3 chars...

```
NSMutableString *mutableString = [NSMutableString new];
[mutableString setString:@"abcdefghijklmnop"];

for (int p = 0; p < [mutableString length]; p++) {
    if (p%4 == 0) {
        [mutableString insertString:@" " atIndex:p];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", mutableString);
```

result: abc def ghi jkl mno p

Answer (score 3):

For a simple task you need a simple solution:

```
NSString *text = @"abcdefghijklmno";
NSString *characterToInsert = @" ";
NSUInteger index = 5;
text = [@[[text substringToIndex:index], [text substringFromIndex:index]] componentsJoinedByString:characterToInsert];
```

And the Swift version (if anyone is interested):

```
var text = "abcdefghijklmno"
let characterToInsert = Substring(" ")
let index = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
text = String(text[..<index] + characterToInsert + text[index...])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableString *liS=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];  
for (int i=0; i < [dir length]; i++) 
{
    NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [lStr characterAtIndex:i]];
    [l1S appendString:ichar];
    if (i==5)  
    {
        [l1S appendString:@" "];
    }
}

dir=l1S;
NSLog(@"updated string is %@",dir);
```

Try this it will helps you

Answer (score 0):

On C++ I've found easier to manipulate a `std::string` and then converting that into a `NSString`. E.g.:

```
std::string text = "abcdefghijklmno";
text.insert(text.begin()+5, ' ');

NSString* result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:text.c_str()];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution without using a mutable string: replace the characters in a range with length 0:

```
NSString * test = @"1234";
// Insert before "3", which is at index 2.
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(2, 0);
NSString * inserted = [test stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range 
    withString:@"abc"]
NSLog(@"%@", inserted); // 12abc34
```