# Simple string concatenation in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, string-concatenation

I have an NSString named 'you' with value "This is a you string!".

I want to concat "123" in 'you', how can I do it?

I am using this code and it is giving an error.

```
you=[you stringByAppendingString:@"123"];
```

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: needs more useful info: what kind of error are you getting, and where?  at compile time or run time or?

Comment: I get "Program Received Signal SIGABRT". I think there might be an error with my logic.

Comment: step through the program until you get the error

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings)

Comment: @UmairKhanJadoon you may want to look at [some neat shortcuts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35071507/105539) to make this far less of a headache.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This code here is working for me

```
NSString *s = @"avant";
s = [s stringByAppendingString:@" - après"];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

> 2012-01-13 11:48:59.442 tabbar[604:207] avant - après

So my guess is that your `you` is a bad pointer that is not `nil` and not the NSString you think it have.

Have you try an NSLog on that value before the call?

Answer (score 47):

You can try this also:

```
you = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", you, @"123"];
```

Answer (score 4):

Code :

```
NSString *you;
you = @"This is you String!";
NSLog(@"you : %@ ",you);

you = [you stringByAppendingString:@"123"];
 NSLog(@"you : %@ ",you);

[you stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@",you,@"123"];
NSLog(@"you : %@ ",you);
```

Result in Console :

[233:907] you : This is you String!

[233:907] you : This is you String!123

[233:907] you : This is you String!123

Comment: No `you=` on the last one? And according to the log, don't the the meaning of this one. On the logs, there is a "tempString"...

Comment: @Larme : Dude that tempString was earlier code.. Why down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote. Still don't understand the last line. You show a different method, but you don't put `you =` before. Indeed, so the last log is normal, but still don't understand the meaning of this one to help the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
NSString *version = @"14.5.1";

NSString *build = @"1.0";


self.versionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@" , @"V : " ,version,@" ( ",build, @" )" ];
```