# How to add strings

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, string-concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I concatenate strings in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c)

I have two strings and wish to make a third string which combines the two by concatenating them.

```
NSString *a = a;
NSString *b = b;
NSString *c = a+b;
```

The problem is that Xcode does`t let me do a+b, so I don't know how to add strings.
I've also tried this:

```
NSStirng *c = @"%@%@",a,b;
```

But it doesn't work too.
Please help me with this noob question!

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
NSString *c = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@%@", a, b]
```

or

```
NSString *c = [a stringByAppendingString:b];
```

The latter being slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSString *c = [a stringByAppendingString: b];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", a, b];
```