# Build a list of constants variable from other constants

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, global-variables, constants

I've just read all of **objective-c global constants variables** Q&A but I found them inappropriate to my problem.

I need a list of variable like this:

```
NSString *baseURL = @"http://example.org";
NSString *mediaURL = @"http://example.org/media/";
NSString *loginURL = @"http://example.org/login/";
NSString *postURL = @"http://example.org/post/";
etc.
```

Of course I can't use this code because it's a very bad approach and if I need to change the base url I must change all variables.
Since I need these variables to be accessed from every class of the app I declared them as global with this approach:

```
// Constants.h
extern NSString *const baseURL;
extern NSString *const mediaURL;
extern NSString *const loginURL;
extern NSString *const postURL;
```

```
// Constants.m
NSString *const baseURL = @"http://example.org";
NSString *const mediaURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@%@", baseURL, @"/media/"];
NSString *const loginURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@%@", baseURL, @"/login/"];
NSString *const postURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@%@", baseURL, @"/post/"];
```

**BUT** I can't do this because I get this error:

```
Initializer element is not a compile-time constant
```

This happens because objects works at runtime.

Now my question is, once and for all I hope, what is a nice and good way to handle this pretty usual scenario in network apps?

I think use a class (or a singleton class) for handle the constants variables is a bit overkill, and it's also too verbose use something like `[MyClass globalVar]` every time I need it.

Ideas about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's old-fashioned but I'd just use preprocessor macros and let constant string concatenation handle it.

```
#define baseURL @"http://example.org"
#define mediaURL baseURL@"/media/"
```

Comment: Uhm, not bad sir. So in this case I need only one .h file, right?

Comment: Yes.  The defines are just pre-compile literal replacements.  (Though, to be semi-standard, one might rename them as FC_BASE_URL and FC_MEDIA_URL or something of the sort.)

Comment: @PhillipMills have you any idea why xcode doesn't auto-suggest me for these variables names?

Comment: Sorry...if you've imported the file that contains the defines, it should.  I've definitely created things like that and had auto-completion work.

Comment: @FredCollins if you need it throughout the app you can import it in the Prefix.pch file.. then you don't need to import it in every file.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define API_ROOT_URL @"https://www.example.org/api"
NSString *const OAuthUrl = API_ROOT_URL @"/oauthToken";
```

[See also.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a MAC now ... can you just try this..

in .h

```
NSString *baseURLString;
extern NSString *const baseURL;
```

in .m

```
baseURLString= @"http://example.org";
NSString *const baseURL= [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", baseURL];
```

I am not sure of this will work..

And also have you seen this answer at SO ... it has all the approaches I know of... [Constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c)

Comment: No it doesn't work for the same reason I've cited in the question. Thanks anyway.