# Constant built from another constant not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I am beginning to delve into iOS development, and am learning Objective C.  My background is Java.
I'm attempting to create a simple console game, and have created the following constants:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static const NSString *ROCK = @"Rock";
static const NSString *PAPER = @"Paper";
static const NSString *SCISSORS = @"Scissors";
static const NSString *LIZZARD = @"Lizzard";
static const NSString *SPOCK = @"Spock";
static const NSArray *WEAPONS = @[SPOCK, ROCK, SCISSORS, LIZZARD, PAPER];
```

The trouble is that I get an error on the last line:  `Initializer element is not a compile-time constant`.

I tried to figure out what this means -- the closest thing I could find was **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055187/build-a-list-of-constants-variable-from-other-constants)** by Fred Collins, where he notes that "This happens because objects works [sic] at runtime."  I'm still not entirely sure what the implication of this is -- how is this different from Java?  (I can definitely do this in Java!)

Regardless, I need some way of initializing `NSArray *WEAPONS`, and I can't make the answers to Fred Collin's question work for me without adding another file.  (He is using a class for his constants, where as my program is simple enough to be contained in the same file as the main method.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304740/initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant-why

Comment: Did you actually tag this with Java? `:/`

Answer (score 1):

One proper way to initialize the array is to do this:

```
static const NSString *ROCK = @"Rock";
static const NSString *PAPER = @"Paper";
static const NSString *SCISSORS = @"Scissors";
static const NSString *LIZZARD = @"Lizzard";
static const NSString *SPOCK = @"Spock";
static const NSArray *WEAPONS = nil;

+ (void)initialize {
    WEAPONS = @[SPOCK, ROCK, SCISSORS, LIZZARD, PAPER];
}
```

The `initialize` class method is a special class method that will only be called once before any instance is ever created or before any method (class or instance) is ever called.

Answer (score 0):

NSArrays are not allowed to be used like that and must be done inside a method. Most everything with the exception of the NSString is disallowed.

Try something like

```
static const NSString *ROCK = @"Rock";
static const NSString *PAPER = @"Paper";
static const NSString *SCISSORS = @"Scissors";
static const NSString *LIZZARD = @"Lizzard";
static const NSString *SPOCK = @"Spock";
static const NSArray *WEAPONS = nil;
- (void)init
{
    WEAPONS = @[SPOCK, ROCK, SCISSORS, LIZZARD, PAPER];
}
```

Comment: Do NOT initialize a static value in an instance method unless you at least verify that it is not yet initialized. Better yet is to initialize the static variable in the `initialize` class method.

Answer (score -1):

The proper way is to do it in the init method of the object, or

```
static const NSArray *WEAPONS = @[@"SPOCK", @"ROCK", @"SCISSORS", @"LIZZARD", @"PAPER"];
```

but I would not recommend this one.

Comment: Could you add an example init method to your answer?

Comment: I just tried your "not recommended" suggestion, and it fails with the same error, even though it's not built from other constants.  Now I am confused.