# Objective C insert variable between 2 strings concat

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, concatenation

I am trying to to do the following (psuedo)

```
NSString *variable = 'Name'; 
NSString *newString = @"Hello, " + variable + @" blah blah";
```

It would appear it is not as simple as the above! Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate strings in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c)

Comment: Please rename this question; it doesn't really have anything to do with Xcode (Xcode is the IDE, this is an Objective-C and Cocoa question).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"Hello, ";
str = [str stringByAppendingString:variable];
str = [str stringByAppendingString:@" blah blah"];
```

If you prefer it as one line statement

```
 NSString *str = [[@"Hello, " stringByAppendingString:variable] stringByAppendingString:@" blah blah"];
```

**Swift**

```
var str = "Hello, " + varaible + "blah blah"
```

OR

```
var str = "Hello, \(variable) blah blah"
```

Comment: I don't know why objective c makes things so complicated, life is more simple than this

Comment: @Osa how about the Swift version :)

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@ blah blah", variable];
```