# Concatenate strings on Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I concatenate strings in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c)

Hello everyone I am new to Objc, I want to concatenate strings of the Integer value with string value.
Here is my code:

```
[runtime setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.movie.runtime]];
```

The result will be: 120

The result that I wish to concatenate string is: 120 Minutes.

Please share me about this.
Thanks

Comment: You should search the website before posting. I would suggest reading this question which can help you with your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-objective-c

Answer (score 6):

I guess, you want this

```
[runtime setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Minutes",self.movie.runtime]];
```

while concatenating would be:

```
NSString *newString = [aString stringByAppendingString:anotherString];
```

for immutable NSStrings

and

```
[aMuteableString appendString:anotherString];
```

for NSMutableStrings