# Macro to concatenate variable number of strings

Tags: objective-c, ios, macros

I wrote this to concatenate two strings:

```
#define Append(x, y) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",x,y]
```

However, what if I have more than just two NSString objects. Is there  way to modify this to work for any number of string values?

Comment: Does it have to be done with a macro? -- it could be accomplished as a function or category with relative ease.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/510269/1032151

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it have to be a macro?  If you can use a method, how about this:

```
- (NSString*)concatenateStrings:(NSString*)string, ...
{
    NSString* result = string;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args,string);

    NSString* arg;
    while((arg = va_arg(args,NSString*)))
        result = [result stringByAppendingString:arg];

    va_end(args);

    return result;
}
```

Which you would call with something like:

```
NSString* result = [self concatenateStrings:@"ABC",@"DEF",@"GHI",nil];
```

Remember to terminate the argument list with a nil.

Comment: Use NSMutableString, don't append NSStrings to NSStrings inside a loop.