# How to plus "NSString" in IOS programming?

Tags: nsstring

How to plus `NSString`?
Example:

```
NSString *a=@"hello";
NSString *b=@"world";
NSString *s=@"";
```

I want:

```
s = "helloworld";
```

Thank for helping.

Comment: You could also try the search function. This brought up [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code.

```
NSString *s= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", a, b];
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is concatenating. And you need to use:

```
NSString *a = @"This ";
NSString *b = @"is a string";
NSString *c= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", a, b];
```

Check out: [objective-c strings a guide for beginners](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/objective-c-strings-a-guide-for-beginners/) for a full list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `stringByAppendingString:` like so -

```
NSString *completeString = [a stringByAppendingString:b];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *a=@"hello";    
NSString *b=@"world";    
NSString *s=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", a, b];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *completeString = [a stringByAppendingString:b];
```

This function is Good and Easy...