# How to concatenate TextView.text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two UITextViews:

```
self.itemsTextView.text;
self.priceTextView.text;
```

I want to concatenate these two like so:

> NSString *data = self.textView.text + self.itemsTextView.text;

I have tried using a colon, as [suggested by this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings), but it doesn't work.

```
NSString *data = [self.textView.text : self.itemsTextView.text];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For concatenating you have several options :

Using `stringWithFormat:`

```
NSString *dataString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.textView.text, self.itemsTextView.text];
```

Using `stringByAppendingString:`

NSMutableString has `appendString:`

Comment: %@ is place holder for one object. As %d is for one integer.

Comment: Those are literals.  %@ is an object literal.

Comment: @BasilSiddiqui Read the docs for the `NSString stringWithFormat:` method. It will tell you all you need to know about format specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
NSString * data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.textView.text,self.itemsTextView.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do this. In addition to the `stringWithFormat:` approaches of the other answers you can do (where `a` and `b` are other strings):

```
NSString *c = [a stringByAppendingString:b];
```

or

```
NSMutableString *c = [a mutableCopy];
[c appendString b];
```