# Is this the standard way to get text from label and concatenate with string in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios6.1

Please bear with me as I'm very new to the world of iOS and Objective-C. I've read Apple's Obj-C primer, as well as a few free ones provided on the web.

On a button press, I'm trying to simply take the text of a label and concatenate it with a string. My mindset is still very much in Android/Java and how simple it could be, but I'm having trouble here. Nonetheless here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)myButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.myLabel.text = [self.myLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@"obj-c is hard =/"];

}
```

It seems pretty standard, but I can imagine myself doing this often so I want to make sure this is correct or what other ways are there to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is correct way. And if you want to use another method then use this one

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ obj-c is hard =/",self.myLabel.text];
```

Comment: `stringWithFormat` will allow you to pass multiple arguments? Unlike `stringByAppendingString` correct?

Answer (score 0):

It is  the standard way to join string.As ios updated syntaxes to make it easy like NSArray and NSDictiornary delaration but for concatenation it has not declared any shortcut way.

[Have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510269/1305001)

**OR**

**you can use a trick to simplify concatenation of string.Pass a parameter to macro and use following joining literal syntax.**

```
#define STRING(text) @""text""

@implementation SPTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *joinedFromLiterals =STRING(@"Congratulations!, ") @"I " @"really " @"enjoy " @"carpenting!";
    NSLog(@"joined string %@",joinedFromLiterals);

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

output is ---------

joined string Congratulations!, I really enjoy carpenting!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct, but there is a gotcha. If you haven't previously set the value of self.myLabel.text, it will be `nil` by default. Then the result of calling any method (like `[self.myLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@"obj-c is hard =/"]`) will also be nil, so `myLabel` will still have empty text. The way Objective-C handles`nil` values is different than handling `null` in Java.
So to be safe, initialize label's text first:

```
self.myLabel.text = @"";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. Sure Objective-C is a bit more verbose than C# or Java or even Visual Basic .net (as I used to work on all those languages) but don't be bugged by those long method names. Although some `#define`s can be very helpful like (rewritten as C inline function):

```
static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
__attribute__((format(NSStirng, 1, 2)) NSString *SKSTR(NSString *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:fmt arguments:args];
    va_end(args);
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    [string autorelease];
#endif
    return string;
}
```

Hope the `__attribute__`s and `#if`s does not confuse you - you can safely ignore them.

To use:

```
self.label.text = SKSTR(@"%@, ugh!", self.label.text); // just like NSLog or snprintf :)
```