# NSLog default break line

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very new to Objective-C and I am starting to learn simple things. In this case, I want to create a `pyramid` using the `*` symbol.

Problem: Everytime `*` is printed, it includes a line break. How can I get rid of it to create a pyramid look? I thought I had to add `\n` to cause a line break in the `Break line` text I added.

Right now, I have this code to create a pyramid:

```
    //Pyramid
    int a,b;
    int x=5;

    for(a = 1; a <= x; a++){

        for(b=1; b<=a; b++){
            NSLog(@"*");
        }

        NSLog(@"Break line");

    }
```

Result:

```
2014-02-23 10:44:35.264 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.266 Pyramid[614:303] Break line
2014-02-23 10:44:35.267 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.267 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.267 Pyramid[614:303] Break line
2014-02-23 10:44:35.268 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.268 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.269 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.269 Pyramid[614:303] Break line
2014-02-23 10:44:35.269 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.270 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.270 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.270 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.271 Pyramid[614:303] Break line
2014-02-23 10:44:35.271 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.272 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.272 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.272 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.273 Pyramid[614:303] *
2014-02-23 10:44:35.273 Pyramid[614:303] Break line
```

Comment: What you're doing is quite good so far. The real problem, though, is that no matter how many times you say `NSLog(@"*")` you will get only ONE log line containing ONE star. You need to accumulate _many_ stars into ONE string so that ONE log line will contain _many_ stars. To do _that_, you will need to learn about NSString and how to combine multiple NSString objects into one...

Comment: NSLog is intended for diagnostic messages, not generalized output.  For generalized output use `printf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, NSLog will always only output one line and you will not be able to avoid that like you can do in Java.  Alternatively you should look into building strings (such as described here: [Shortcuts in Objective-C to concatenate NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings)).

An example:

```
//Pyramid
int a,b;
int x=5;

for(a = 1; a <= x; a++){
    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];
    for(b=1; b <= a; b++){
        [string appendString:@"*"];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

Comment: All answers are good but I like this solution :) I am also trying to figure it out myself as explained by @matt. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

NSLog always outputs a newline at the end, as well as other info at the start.

You can use `printf("*");` to output to the console without a newline. Include `\n` when you want a newline.

```
for (NSUInteger outerIndex = 1; outerIndex <= 5; ++outerIndex) {
    for (NSUInteger innerIndex = 1; innerIndex <= outerIndex; ++innerIndex) {
        printf("*");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Even though my answer is the accepted one, this answer is good for a non-NSLog approach.