# how to save a file in objective c in xcode with date string concatenated in name?

Tags: objective-c

i want to save an image with new name every time in xcode using objective c.
how to do that? i want to add a time string in the name, and i have stored time string in a variable. how to concatenate that variable with the name.
code which i am using is as---

```
    NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YY HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateString);`

    NSData *myImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:@"/Users/name/Desktop/myimage.jpg" contents:myImageData attributes:nil];
```

Comment: Is this really for iPhone? Where would `/Users/name/Desktop/` be on a iPhone?

Comment: you'll see a lot of good hints here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/shortcuts-in-objective-c-to-concatenate-nsstrings

Comment: be aware that colons are not allowed in HFS(+)

Comment: i am working with the simulator , so right now i am saving these images in the mac.

Answer (score 0):

You already have it 95% complete.  You don't want *concatenation*, as such, as you want to preserve the `.jpg` file extension, so use `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` to create the filename:

```
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/name/Desktop/myimage-%@".jpg", dateString];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:filename contents:myImageData attributes:nil];
```

Hints:

1. Don't hardcode the path like that; get the user's *Documents* folder using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`.
2. You probably don't want a space in the formatted date string.

Comment: please tell about some good pdf to learn the concepts of ios and objective c.