# Adding/Concatenating two textfield in one label in iOS

Tags: ios

I have two `textfield` and one label, say Txt1 and Txt2 and result, i want to add both input of text field and display it on one label in same view controller.

 So how can i do this? Thank you.

Comment: NSString *result =[NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", Txt1.text, Txt2.text];
label.text=result;

Comment: Thanks it really worked :)

Comment: @Arjun Ker please first R&D on stackoverflow than ask question. Thanks your solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/shortcuts-in-objective-c-to-concatenate-nsstrings

Comment: Arjun ker please refer my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var txt2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txt1: UITextField!

    //Setting value t label

    label.text = txt1.text! + txt2.text!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 yourLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",txtField1.text,txtField2.text];
```