# objective c how to add string value to integer?

Tags: objective-c

I have label and I want to give it value of two elements that one of them NSInteger and the other string

```
_imgIndex.text = [@(index+1) stringValue]; //how to add string here?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/shortcuts-in-objective-c-to-concatenate-nsstrings

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have an integer value (`index`) and a Obj-C string object (`stringValue`) and you want to concatenate them. There are lots of ways of doing this, here are two:

`_imgIndex.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu%@",index,stringValue];`

The other technique would be to first convert the integer into a string, then concatenate the other string:

`_imgIndex.text = [@(index).description stringByAppendingString:stringValue];`