# How to print text from array with some other string?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsstring

I'm new to Objective-C and I couldn't find a direct solution for my problem where it is explained how to add string behind or in front of an array value .
I try to get some text from an array and add some other string behind or infront of it (will be used in tableviewcell). In Android it's working just with + signs, that's why I couldn't handle it here.
I try to do something like below:

```
"some text" +[arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] + "some text"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `stringWithFormat` to concatenate those values, or you can use `NSMutableString` as well

**Use this**

```
NSString* finalText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some text %@ some text",[arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

**Another way**

```
NSMutableString* finalString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"test Text"];
[finalString appendString:[arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[finalString appendString:@"test Text 2"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Short:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", "some text", [arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], "some text"];
```

For further answers see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/510444/9310455